# How to align a logo on the left and navigation on the right using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I need help to align a logo on the left and navigation on the right using html and css.

I want it to be like this image > [image]

I've been trying different ways to change my css format and it just wouldn't work.

Here is my html and css

```css
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Hoefler Text;
    background-color: rgb(233, 245, 248);
}
header{
    margin: 3% 10% 3% 10%;
    padding: 37px 161px;
     align-items: center; 
}
@media screen and { (max-width: 700px)}
    .header {
        width: auto;
        float: none;

 }
 
.main-nav{
    font-family: Hoefler Text;
    font-size: .8rem;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.main-nav li { float: left;}
    
.main-nav li a {
    display:block;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    padding:10px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

.main-nav li:hover{
    background: #ADD8E6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>*</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="*">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="*"type="image/jpg"> 
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="header">
        <a href='*' ><img src='*' alt='logo'/></a>
       
        <ul class="main-nav">
            <li><a href="*">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="*"> Education</a></li>
            <li><a href="*"> Experience</a></li>
            <li><a href="*">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="*">Contact Me</a></li>
         </ul>
    </nav>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you at least dive into css a little before asking questions on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 3):

To solve this problem and align a logo on the left and links on the right of a nav bar you can use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox). Flexbox is preferable to trying to use floats, which is a somewhat antiquated way of doing layouts.

To accomplish this and make it look a bit nicer and be more semantic, I have modified your HTML slightly and renamed some of your classes. I've also added some additional default styling tips you may find helpful as a beginner. Take a look:

```css
/*
 * Ensure a better box-sizing model by using the universal
 * selector `*` and setting it to inherit. We will then
 * change the box-sizing property on the root element
 * so other elements inherit from that when it is not
 * set explicitly on a closer parent element.
 */

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: inherit; 
}

/* 
 * 1. Set the root box-sizing model that other elements
 *    will inherit if it is not set on a closer parent.
 * 2. Add a fallback-font stack that will work across
 *    every browser and device in case your custom font
 *    doesn't load, loads slowly, or doesn't have a glyph
 *    for a specific character.
 * 3. Set an accessible default font-size that will be set
 *    according to user's browser settings (usually 16px).
 */

 
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family:
    /* Newer browsers */
    system-ui,
    /* Safari for OS X and iOS (San Francisco) */
    -apple-system,
    /* Chrome < 56 for OS X (San Francisco) */
    BlinkMacSystemFont,
    /* Windows */
    'Segoe UI',
    /* Android */
    Roboto,
    /* Basic web fallback */
    'Helvetica Neue',
    Helvetica,
    Arial,
    sans-serif,
    /* Emoji fonts */
    'Apple Color Emoji',
    'Segoe UI Emoji',
    'Segoe UI Symbol',
    'Noto Color Emoji';
  font-size: 1em;
}

/* 
 * Add smooth scrolling for users who do not turn it off.
 *  This is how you should structure media queries
 */

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
}

/* 
 * You wisely removed the default margin from the body,
 * but default padding is already 0 so setting that is
 * is not necessary. I like to set the min-height of the
 * body so that it always takes up the entire viewport.
 * Use the new `dvh` unit which take into account mobile
 * browser address and tab bars. Use `vh` as a fallback.
 */

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100dvh;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Hoefler Text;
  background-color: rgb(233, 245, 248);
}

/* 
 * Now the bar itself is called masthead, set the padding and 
 * background color. Add any other styles you want for the bar
 * like `position: sticky` to keep it stuck to the top of the
 * page.
 */
  
.masthead {
  background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.9);
  padding: 1.75rem 0;
}

/*
 * Make a container right inside the masthead to limit the
 * max-width of the content. You can reuse in the page content.
 */

.container {
  /* Use any sizes you prefer here, but the min() function
     is very good for responsive containers */
  max-width: min(96%, 1140px); 
  margin: 0 auto; /* to center the container horizontally */
}

/* 
 * The <nav> element now called .primary-nav. Set flex and
 * the flex properties align-items and justify-content here.
 * The default flex-direction is `row` so align-items will
 * align things vertically and justify-content will align
 * horizontally. space-between value will set all the space
 * between the two child elements (the logo link and the 
 * nav-links <ul> element.
 */

.primary-nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

/* 
 * Renamed the <ul> element to .nav-links. 
 * Set display: flex here too and reset the list styles.
 */
   
.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* 
 * Added a class for each link (calling them .nav-link). 
 * Set some margin to keep the links away from each other
 */

.nav-links li {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.nav-links li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

/* 
 * Set the styles on the links. It would probably be better
 * to just add a class to all the links and select them that
 * way instead though.
 */
  
.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(0, 53, 128);
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

/* 
 * Create effects for the different link states if you  want.
 * hover, focus, active, etc.
 */

.nav-link:hover {
  color: rgb(73, 0, 106);
} 

/*
 * Add a screen-reader only class so that you can make
 * things invisible but still seen by screen readers
 * and web crawlers, so you get the accessibility and
 * SEO benefits of a header for the masthead while
 * still being able to just use a logo.
 */

.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  clip-path: inset(100%);
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
 <!-- Note the changed class names and added elements.
  I change the <a> around the logo to have href="/"
  to make it link to index page, which is expected
  behavior.

  Your <head> section mostly looks good but 
  I'd strongly suggest not using a .jpg for the
  favicon/shortcut-icon. Use either .svg or .ico
  maybe combined with some .png for apple-touch-icon and 
  android-chrome. You can use a free favicon generator 
  online (link below code snippet and it will give you
  all the filetypes and the markup you need. -->

<header class="masthead">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="primary-nav">
      <h1 class="sr-only">Page Name</h1>
      <a href='/'><img src='*' alt='logo'></a>
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="home.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="education.html" class="nav-link">Education</a></li>
        <li><a href="experience.html" class="nav-link">Experience</a></li>
        <li><a href="projects.html" class="nav-link">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact Me</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

If you need a favicon generator to convert your jpg into all the
right favicon file types you need (and get the markup to use for them, you can check out this [favicon converter at favicon.io](https://favicon.io/favicon-converter/) or [their favicon generator](https://favicon.io/favicon-generator/) that will create them from scratch from text. Both are useful tools for getting your favicons done quickly.

If you want to play around with my code directly, you can also [check out my CodePen](https://codepen.io/stephenirving/pen/abxBvLK) and fork this example.

One last thing I would like to point out is that when you attempted to make a media query, you structured it incorrectly by placing the brackets in the wrong place. So, if you want to add media queries to this, as you probably will, your media query should have been structured like this:

```css
/* 
 * Prefer `em` to `px` for media queries (just divide `px` by 16) 
 * this is because it is better for accessibility for users
 * who change their default font-size in the browser.
 */

@media screen and (max-width: 27.25em) {
   .masthead > .container {
      max-width: 100%;
      padding: 0.5rem 0;

   }
}
```

Hope this has been helpful to you!

Comment: @codewithchiefkabbz make sure to check out my edits. Improved my answer about 30m after posting.

Answer (score 0):

You can arrange elements inside a div using flex. The "justify-content: space-between" property positions these elements so they extend to the edges of the parent container. Additionally "align-items: center" vertically centers the elements within the container.
Here's an example of aligning a logo on the left and navigation on the right using HTML and CSS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Topbar Example</title>
  <style>
    /* Style for the topbar */
    .topbar {
      background-color: #333;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 10px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
    }

    /* Style for the logo */
    .logo {
      font-size: 24px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    /* Style for the navigation */
    .navigation {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .navigation li {
      display: inline;
      margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .navigation li a {
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topbar">
  <!-- Logo on the left -->
  <div class="logo">Your Logo</div>
  <!-- Navigation on the right -->
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="home.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="education.html" class="nav-link">Education</a></li>
    <li><a href="experience.html" class="nav-link">Experience</a></li>
    <li><a href="projects.html" class="nav-link">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact Me</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please give a class name to the anchor link which is the parent of image logo.
Now we can use **flexbox** to achieve what you have asked for.
I have used the html and css file provided in your question and did some modifications in the code to achieve your design. You can change the color codes of background, font and also the mobile/tablet view design structure as per your requirement.

The alignment criteria which you have asked for is majorly achieved using/giving the below designs to the '.header' class name element.

```
display: flex; // It specifies that all the child of the element will now follow flexbox model
flex-direction: row; // both the flexbox children will come one after another in a single line/row.
align-items: center; // vertically aligns all the content to center
justify-content: space-between; // It will strech the box to cover the whole screen and will provide dynamic space between the two children i.e., the logo an the <ul> list.
```

To see the complete code, please look at the code snippet below.

```css
        *,
        *:before,
        *:after {
          box-sizing: border-box;
          font-family: Hoefler Text;
          overflow-x: hidden;
        }

        /* below mobile & ipad */
        @media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
          .header {
            width: 100%;
          }
        }

        .header {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: space-between;
          width: 100vw;
          margin: 0 auto;
          padding: 10px 40px;
          background: olive;
        }

        .header .logo-link {
          width: 100px;
          height: 100%;
        }

        .header .logo {
          width: 100%
        }

        .header .main-nav {
          font-size: 16px;
          list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
          background-color: grey;
        }

        .main-nav li {
          float: left;
        }

        .main-nav li a {
          display: block;
          color: #ffffff;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 10px 12px;
          text-decoration: none;
          cursor: pointer;
        }

        .main-nav li:hover {
          background: #add8e6;
        }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">

        <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <title>*</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="*">
          <link rel="shortcut icon" href="*" type="image/jpg">
        </head>
        <body>
          <nav class="header">
            <a href='#' class="logo-link">
              <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2235130/pexels-photo-2235130.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600" class="logo" alt="logo" /></a>
            <ul class="main-nav">
              <li><a href="*">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="*"> Education</a></li>
              <li><a href="*"> Experience</a></li>
              <li><a href="*">Projects</a></li>
              <li><a href="*">Contact Me</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution that i can provide you. Just make the nav tag as block add display style as flex; then align it as center and justify-content is space-between. then add the desired width to both of your blocks. for example

```css
.header{  
  display: flex;
  /* align items in center to make the logo and navigation in center of your nav bar*/
  align-items: center;
  /* it will divide the width and stick both blocks to left and right*/
  justify-content: space-between;
  width:100%;
}

.logo{
  /* set desired width*/
  width: auto;
}

.main-nav{
  
  /* set desired width*/
  width: auto;
  /* this below styling is to align the menu on navigation bar*/
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  gap:50px;

}
```

```html
<nav class="header">
    
        <a href='*'  class="logo"><img src='*' alt='logo'/></a>
       
        <ul class="main-nav">
            <li><a href="*">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="*"> Education</a></li>
            <li><a href="*"> Experience</a></li>
            <li><a href="*">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="*">Contact Me</a></li>
         </ul>
    </nav>
```